# Can not read .mat file into python

Tags: python, hdf5, mat, h5py

I have been trying for days, searching for the proper way to read this file in my python project. Which is an ordinary matlab datastructure file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E1w1eQn6pTcQ1lkhGMJzmB5ugtmaDPht

I am familiar about how to read h5 files which seems to be the case with this .mat file since it doesn't allow scipy.loadmat to read it. So I used h5py.Read().

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('./imgIdx.mat','r')
d = f['imgIdx/anno']
print(d[1000])     # accessing an arbitrary object

[<HDF5 object reference>]
```

Which is an object that I can't deal with 
This is supposed to be a m x 4 matrix 
where m >= 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following hints from the `object reference` section in the docs: 
http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html

```
In [348]: d = f['imgIdx/anno']
In [349]: d[1000]
Out[349]: array([<HDF5 object reference>], dtype=object)
In [350]: d[1000].item()
Out[350]: <HDF5 object reference>
In [351]: f[d[1000].item()]
Out[351]: <HDF5 dataset "N4": shape (4, 2), type "<f8">
In [352]: f[d[1000].item()][:]
Out[352]: 
array([[ 87., 447.],
       [158., 160.],
       [446., 586.],
       [325., 283.]])
```

I also used `h5dump` in the shell to look at the file and its contents.

Comment: That's precise and on point. Thanks I can now understand it through such a minimal example focusing on what's needed.